# Write a matrix to a string

Tags: c++, matrix

Suppose you have a matrix of N*M of floats, I want to have a C++ function to transform this matrix to a string buffer (using \t as separator between values of the same line and \n as return to new line), something like:

```
String converteMatrixToString( vector< vector<float> > )
{
   /* ... */
   return converted;
}
```

Is there any already existing C++ function to do it ?

Comment: No. You'll need to write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your matrix were an actual type, you could make it output streamable which is the preferred way to make things "convertible to string". That would allow you from outputing a matrix to `std::cout` or any other kind of stream, including using `std::lexical_cast`.

Right now, the best you can do is use a `std::ostringstream`. Here in pseudocode:

```
std::ostringstream stream;

foreach( row in matrix )
{
   foreach( value in row )
       stream << value << '\t';
   stream << '\n';
}

return stream.str();
```